# return integer from defined exception in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to define an exception which returns int. My code is given below. It's showing error.

```
class BadLengthException : public exception {
    public:
        int x;

    BadLengthException(int n){
        x =n;
    }

    virtual const int what() const throw ()  {
        return x;
    }
};
```

The error is:

> solution.cc:12:22: error: conflicting return type specified for
>   ‘virtual const int BadLengthException::what() const’
>       virtual const int what() const throw ()  {
>                         ^~~~ In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/exception:38:0,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:39,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
>                    from solution.cc:1: /usr/include/c++/7/bits/exception.h:69:5: error:   overriding ‘virtual
>   const char* std::exception::what() const’
>        what() const _GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE_DYN _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT;

Comment: as a side note: don't use `virtual` to mark methods in derived classes that override base class virtual member functions, use dedicated `override` specifier instead.

Comment: @paler123 Naw, use virtual final override -- more keywords, more better!

Comment: this should be the exercise series on [Inherited Code](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/inherited-code/problem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`exception::what()` returns a `const char*`, you can't change that. But you can define another method to return the `int`, eg:

```
class BadLengthException : public std::length_error {
private:
    int x;
public:
    BadLengthException(int n) : std::length_error("bad length"), x(n) { }
    int getLength() const { return x; }
};
```

And then call it in your `catch` statements, eg:

```
catch (const BadLengthException &e) {
    int length = e.getLength();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually, it would probably make more sense to use `std::length_error` instead: "*It reports errors that result from attempts to exceed implementation defined length limits for some object.*"

Answer (score 3):

Hey I think you are doing the inherited code on hackerrank, I faced the same issue, also we can't change the other part of the code, so we have to override the what function,

For your C++ 11:

Now we have our int n, but we must convert it to char* to return it,

first convert it to a string with to_string() 
then make that a const shar*   (aka c string)  using  .c_str()

Our class now becomes:

```
class BadLengthException : public exception{
    public:
    string str;

    BadLengthException(int n){
        str = to_string(n);
    }
    const char * what () const throw() {

        return str.c_str() ;
    }
};
```